# How can I get N elements from Dataset at a time, without collecting them in memory?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a use case where I need to collect the contents of a Dataset, but since this requires memory on my driver, I want to do it 'N' at a time, sequentially. 
I would like to query only once, to create the Dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
val dfSrc = (1 to 100).map(i => (i,scala.util.Random.nextDouble())).toDF("id","x")

// define an index, e.g. with row_number 
val dsWithRnb = dfSrc
   .withColumn("rnb",row_number().over(Window.orderBy($"id")))
   .cache 

// get rows in chunks of 10
val N = 10
(0L to dsWithRnb.count).grouped(N).foreach{batch =>     
   // collect batch
   val batchData = dsWithRnb.where($"rnb".isin(batch:_*)).collect()
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [toLocalIterator](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@toLocalIterator():java.util.Iterator[T])
it will give an iterator in the driver to the elements in the ds

for example:

```
val ds = ...
ds
  .cache
  .toLocalIterator
  .grouped(N)
  .map(nRows => ...)
```